# EF Core - Cascade deletes happening the other way around

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I have a simple EF Core model with two entities, Location, and Address where a Location must always have an Address.

The entities and their configuration is as follow:

```
public class Location {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
public class Address {
    public virtual int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string LineOne { get; set; }
    public string LineTwo { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string ZipPostCode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string LandlinePhone { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
}

// Context configuration
...
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
...
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().HasOne(l => l.Address).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
...
}
...
```

**Note:** The address entity does not have a reference back to the location.

With the above configuration, deleting a location should delete its address but deleting the address should result in an reference integrity error. Trying the above with a unit test using EF InMemory database gives an unexpected outcome:

```
    [Test]
    public void DeleteAddressShouldNotDeleteLocation() {
        var address = new Address();
        var location = new Location() {Address = address};
        _context.Locations.Add(location);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        // Delete the address added above
        _context.Addresses.Remove(_context.Addresses.Single());
        _context.SaveChanges();

        Assert.AreEqual(1, _context.Locations.Count()); --> ALWAYS FAILS AS THE LOCATION IS CASCADE DELETED
    }
```

This also happens on our production server (Azure SQL) so it shouldn't be an issue with EF Core.

Is there a reason why EF is cascading the address deletion to the Location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With the above configuration, deleting a location should delete its address but deleting the address should result in an reference integrity error

Negative. Every relationship (except many-to-many) has *principal* and *dependent* (see [Relationships - Definitions of terms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#definition-of-terms)). Cascade delete works from principal (referenced) to dependent (referencing). If cascade delete is disabled, then principal cannot be deleted if there are references to it.

So, who is the dependent in your case? The dependent is always the one who has the FK reference to the other, i.e. `Location`, hence the behavior you are experiencing.

If you want to be other way around, remove the `AddressId` FK from `Location` and add `LocationId` FK to `Address` (or configure/use the so called "shared primary key association" by making `Address` PK also a FK).

But note that there is no relational design which meets all your requirements. The closest (will meet 2 of 3) is to keep the current design with `DeleteBehavior.Restrict`. This way

1. Location must always have an Address - satisfied.
2. deleting the address should result in an reference integrity error - satisfied
3. deleting a location should delete its address - not satisfied, and cannot be, since the location is not owning the address.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Oh, I see your point so in my case the principal is Address. I assume a fix would be to force the address not to delete the location then, correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed (`DeleteBehavior.Restrict`). That would be closest to your requirements - will meet 2 of 3. Just "deleting a location should delete its address" cannot happen since location is not owning the address.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)` - counter-intuitive, but works on my project. 
Think of it as "do not let address be deleted if there is a location with it".

Additional `.IsRequired()` for this relationship will enforce one address - as you stated in your question (Location always have an address).

Comment: Thank you. I just tried your suggestion with no luck. The address is still deleting the location entity :(

Comment: Just to be sure and it may be obvious - if you are using ef code-first - did you rolled back migration that setup your configuration an created + applied new migration with `Restrict` behaviour?

Comment: I actually have unit tests that check cascade deletes using EF InMemory Db

Comment: Could [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/3924) be the probable cause when testing with InMemory?

Comment: It might be. It is working fine for other relationships that have cascade deletes enabled though

Comment: Ok, a bit of a shot in the dark, but try to remove all argument configurations and replace them with fluent configurations - its possible, that there is a problem with using both of them with InMemory. Also, I would redo this test with SqlLite just to be sure - much better support for relationships.